# Create PDF From a Database Object and Send it Via Email

Tags: ms-access, pdf, pdf-generation, ms-access-2007, vba

In VBA for Access 2007 I wish to create a PDF document and email that document out to someone. How would I go about creating a PDF document in VBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the SendObject method of the DoCmd object:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb214075(v=office.12).aspx

```
DoCmd.SendObject acSendReport, "Employees", acFormatPDF, _
    "Nancy Davolio; Andrew Fuller", "Joan Weber", , _
    "Current Spreadsheet of Employees", , False
```

To save in PDF format, you must first install an add-on:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/print-share-and-protect-files-in-the-pdf-and-xps-file-formats-HA010167527.aspx

Comment: Just to add that for those of us who dont have access 2007 or above there is a way of doing this without having to buy/install a PDF print driver. Check it out here http://www.lebans.com/reporttopdf.htm

Comment: And if you want to use Access to send PDFs from other applications (the Lebans utility only works with Access reports), PDFCreator is automatable from within VBA.